# Devolver 1 o 0 dependiendo del resultado que arroje la consulta

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
Select L.idtipolocalidad from Localidad L 
inner join RecepcionDetalleAbierta RDA on RDA.idLocalidadAlmacenado = L.IdLocalidad 
inner join Localidad L1 on RDA.IdLocalidad = L1.IdLocalidad where l1.Codigo = 'PREC36'
group by L.IdTipoLocalidad`
```

Me trae como resultado un **5** pero lo que intento hacer es que *si trae 5 guardar en una variable 1 de lo contrario 0*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Este es mi intento pero no me queda

```
SET @vEnvioCompleto = (SELECT CASE WHEN L.IdTipoLocalidad = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM RecepcionDetalleAbierta RDA
                    INNER JOIN Localidad L ON L.IdLocalidad = RDA.IdLocalidadAlmacenado
                    inner join Localidad L1 on RDA.IdLocalidad = L1.IdLocalidad
                    WHERE L.Codigo = 'PREC36')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que la consulta devuelve un solo registro?¿Hace falta pivotear todas esas tablas si solo usas los datos de una sola?¿Que error te da?

Comment: @Javier puedes añadir el error que te sale o el resultado.

Comment: Agregue unas capturas

Comment: No hay ningún error, solo que estas interpretando mal el  `SET` este asigna mas no muestra el resultado asignado: Prueba poniendo después de tu select esto `SELECT @vEnvioCompleto` y seguro te dara 1.

Comment: ya me quedo solo que ahora no se debolver el resultado

Comment: @Javierfr ¿Como lo quieres recibir? Estas llamando el codigo como un  Store Procedure de forma interna o lo llamas a una petición desde una aplicación.

Comment: se puede imprimir el dato que tiene una variable en sql y verla como se hace con php?

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres ver el resultado en el management studio entonces tiene que hacer despues de la asignación a la variable:

```
Select @vEnvioCompleto
```

Una recomendación en el set de la variable @vEnvioCompleto tienes que limitar el result set a 1 solo resultado para que no te de error si en algún momento la consulta llega a retornar más de un registro. Eso lo puedes hacer utilizando  Top

```
 set @vEnvioCompleto = (select top 1 ... el resto de tu consulta)
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql

Si el resultado lo necesitas leer desde una aplicación pudieras crear un Stored Procedure con tu consulta y hacer el llamado a dicho Stored desde la aplicación.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure

Para ejecutar el stored y leer la información que regresa, eso depende de la aplicación que haga el llamado.